# Confusion with length contraction

Tags: special-relativity

Why is it called length "contraction" when an approaching rod can appear elongated?

http://www.spacetimetravel.org/bewegung/bewegung3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a moving object may *look* like depends on light travelling to the eye from different points on the object. To reach the eye simultaneously the light must have left different points on the moving object at different times. This can all get complicated quite rapidly!

*Length contraction* is a much simpler phenomenon (if you've grasped the basics of Special Relativity as a theory about the nature of space-time!). In a frame of reference in which a rod is moving we must make simultaneous measurements of the positions of the ends of the rod against our stationary ruler. The length we get for the rod is less than the rod's length in a frame of reference in which it is stationary (so in which our measurements of the positions of its ends need not be simultaneous).

Comment: Thanks, I just got it when I read this answer from the user "Alfred Centauri" " in SR, observing (or measuring) length contraction does not mean to photograph length contraction. Rather, it means recording events: "the front of the rod was at this location at the same (coordinate) time as the rear of the rod was at this other location; the rod's (coordinate) length is thus...""